# Flow designer-Sequential approvals for a record 3levels

Tags: servicenow, email-notifications

I’m trying to do a flow designer for 3 levels of approvals if X approves send approval request to Y, if Y approves send approval request to Z and set timer for each approval request as 15days. Send reminder notification for 7 days on 8th day, for every approval request send a notification if rejected send a notification and update record to draft state, if cancelled after 15days send cancelled notification and set state to draft. I created a flow for all 3 levels and they are working fine but I’m stuck at creating reminder notifications. For every approval I should calculate time from previous approval approved time. Which I couldn’t. Someone please help me with this.